# Exception.ToString() throws exception

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to log an exception using the `Exception.ToString()` method. However, I get a new exception from the `ToString()` method - it seems to originate from the stack trace handling. 
The original error is a FileNotFoundException. Here is the output:

```
The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void*, Int32, System.RuntimeFieldHandleInternal, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, System.RuntimeType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat)
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(System.Exception, Boolean)
   at System.Exception.GetStackTrace(Boolean)
   at System.Exception.get_StackTrace()
   at System.IO.FileNotFoundException.ToString()
   at InSQLMDASDriver.InSQLMDASDriver.Init(System.String, System.String)
   at InSQLMDASDriver.InSQLMDASDriverLogic.InSQLMDASDriverLogicInit(System.String, System.String)
   at InSQLMDASDriver.InSQLMDASDriverLogic..ctor(System.String, System.String)
   at InSQLMDASDriverWCFServer.Service1.MainTread()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

When I run this code I can verify that the exception is thrown from Exception.ToString():

```
    private void Init(string defaultWindowName, string mainPath)
    {    
       try 
       {

            // code that fails

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
             string errorAsString = GetErrorAsString(e);

             Logger.Log(string.Format("Init error at line block {0}: {1}", initBlockCounter, errorAsString), level: LogLevel.Error);


             throw new Exception("FileNotFoundException: " + e.FileName + ", " + e.FusionLog, e);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
              string errorAsString = GetErrorAsString(e);

              Logger.Log(string.Format("Init error at line block {0}: {1}", initBlockCounter, errorAsString), level: LogLevel.Error);


          throw;
      }
}

    string GetErrorAsString(Exception e)
    {
         try
         {
             return e.ToString();
         }
         catch(Exception ne)
         {
                     return e.Message + " (ERROR getting stacktrace: " + ne.Message + ")";
          }
    }
```

Why does this happen..?

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls `GetErrorAsString` ?

Comment: Can you show that exception? But at first glance, it might be due to the e object being null. check it.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso - if that were the case the `e.Message` reference in the `catch(Exception ne)` part would cause a re-throw again...

Comment: And that exactly might be the case where he has the error. His own ToString is going to the catch.

Comment: Try removing some of the noise. You are rethrowing exceptions and doing a lot of work that is not core to your question. How much can you remove without changing the behaviour?

Comment: According to the stacktrace your code never reaches `GetErrorAsString()`. `Exception.ToString()` will not throw `FileNotFoundException` in any case.

Comment: GetErrorAsString() was added after the original problem to try to find out what was going on. I haven't posted the output from that method yet.

Comment: I'm guessing the runtime is trying to load an assembly that it cannot find during the creation of the stack trace. Can you show us the Message of the FileNotFoundException?

Comment: @user1919998 Please do. As well as the complete `Init` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a description that matches my issue where an assembly failing to load  causes a FileNotFoundException, and calling ToString() gives another exception:

> Here is what happens. The
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject needs
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives assembly. But it is not
> present, so it tries to throw the FileNotFoundException. It creates
> the exception object and then it wants to set the stack trace for it.
> So it looks at the topmost frame of the exception stack trace, finds
> the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method there and
> tries to use reflection to get its parameters info. When looking at
> the 2nd parameter of the method which is of type
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings, it tries to build the metadata
> structure for this parameter type. And accidentally, one of the fields
> of this type is of the StreamingContext type that comes from the
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives assembly. To get details on
> the type, it attempts to load this assembly - and since it doesn't
> exist (that was the reason for the original exception we are trying to
> build stack trace for), it throws an exception and the result is what
> you can see.

See the bug report and discussion there: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/5203. It should be fixed meanwhile.

Comment: please summarize the link here