# Cannot Print Exception String in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to run this line of code for connecting to mysql using csharp and dotnet core 2.1.300 (sdk).

```
 string server = "localhost";
 string database = "db";
 string uid = "root";
 string password = "";
 string connectionString;
 connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

But last line will raise an exception that I cannot understand what goes wrong to resolve it.
running dll of project using dotnet shows me this:

```
dotnet : 
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet C:\Users\foo\bar\project ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


Unhandled Exception: 


Cannot print exception string because Exception.ToString() failed.
```

I tried recommendations by posts like this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387540/exception-tostring-throws-exception) and added `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives` assembly to my references in VS 2017 but it did not help.

I'm modifying this csharp project actually, so that it write its output to a database. 
https://github.com/vcsjones/AuthenticodeLint

Changing the MySqlException to Exception will result in this output:

```
Unhandled Exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* 
methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] 
typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& 
lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean 
mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& 
ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, 
RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Int32 attributeCtorToken, Boolean mustBeInheritable)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ShowInStackTrace(MethodBase mb)
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
....
```

Comment: Is it on the `connection.Open();` line? Can we get a full stack trace please?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: I cannot print stack trace.(Or maybe I don't know how to do it! From my understanding, although I'm catching the exception raised by that last line, printing the stack trace or exception message raises another exception and fails! )

Comment: I'm handling exception like this:
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {

                verboseWriter.LogMessage(ex.StackTrace);
            }
Even if I comment out this line 
verboseWriter.LogMessage(ex.StackTrace);
I still get that "Unhandled Exception" error.

Comment: Change your exception to `Exception` not `MySqlException`. What do you get then when you put a breakpoint there and then check `Message`... If that doesn't work have you tried at least version 2.2; if I remember correctly this was an issue in 2.1x...

Comment: I updated my post as you asked (changed to Exception).

Comment: well at least you have something useful now! Can you open up Package Manager and then run `Install-Package System.Drawing.Common -Version 4.6.0`... Once done, can you see if you still have the issue? I think by default this wasn't included in core.

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thanks a lot. I'm new in using VS and dotnet and were struggling with this problem since morning :\\\\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing your exception type, we have something to go after.

> Unhandled Exception: 
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* 
>   methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] 
>   typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& 
>   lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean 
>   mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& 
>   ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, 
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Int32 attributeCtorToken, Boolean mustBeInheritable)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
>      at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ShowInStackTrace(MethodBase mb)
>      at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
>   ....

This exception **is caused by not having `System.Drawing.Common`** library. Open up Package Manager and then run `Install-Package System.Drawing.Common -Version 4.6.0`

In this version you have, the library doesn't have the dependencies you need, `System.Drawing.Common`, they should have updated this to include it.